# Cannot set custom parameter with python social auth

Tags: python, django, python-social-auth

I've followed docs to set my custom parameter, but I still cannot get it from my custom pipeline function.

Here is the setting:

In settings.py:

```
FIELDS_STORED_IN_SESSION = ['tgtid']

SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    'mindex.users.auth.pipeline.user_data',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
    'social.pipeline.user.create_user',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
    'social.pipeline.user.user_details',
    'mindex.users.auth.pipeline.save_token',
    'mindex.users.auth.pipeline.add_social',
)
```

Example of redirect url is:

```
/login/facebook/?tgtid=1&next=/report/1/connect_task/
```

In my add_social function, I cannot read tgtid, strategy.session_get('tgtid') returns None. The signature of add_social function is:

```
add_social(strategy, social, response, *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured out myself.

Just add the following line to settings.py:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_FIELDS_STORED_IN_SESSION = ('tgtid', )
```